# ExtJS - Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-chart

How to offset the items in a stacked bar chart for any given bar?

```
Bar 1: 4 items (150,290,200,50)
Bar 2: only 2 items (--, --, 240,45)
```

I want to start the item with value 240 at a given offset instead of starting at 0 ( ex: I want to start it at 600 and show 240 from there). From 0 to 600, it will be blank/white space.

I can post my example code if that's of any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight forward settings to do this. You will have to override the renderer and provide your custom styling to achieve the offset effect. The `Ext.chart.series.Series` does have a `renderer` method.

The method takes five parameters:

1. sprite - A class with all sprite information.
2. record - The current record being rendered.
3. attributes - Attributes used of the drawing.
4. index - index of the record being processed.
5. store - store used for the chart.

You need to check if your record contains a null value. If so, you need to modify the attributes object with appropriate values and return it back. You can view the [default renderer method](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/source/Series.html#Ext-chart.series.Series-cfg-renderer) from the source code.

```
renderer: function(sprite,record,attributes,index,store) {
    //Modify the attributes object according to your needs 
    return attributes;
},
```

But I couldn't come up with a correct logic to modify the drawing values stored in attributes class.

Comment: This is really very good information. If I want to add a condition to check which item is redering how can I do that? If I can find out which item is rendering, I can add an Offset in my data and then set the color to White to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

The *record* argument of the renderer function tells you which record is being rendered.